# Axes in pst-3dplot and pst-solides3d

Tags: xetex, pstricks, graphs, pst-solides3d, pst-3dplot

This is just a simple question regarding the comparison of the axes using `pst-3dplot` and `pst-solides3d` packages. The MWE and the output are as follows:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{pstricks, pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[viewpoint=5 30 45 rtp2xyz,Decran=5 , Alpha=51](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psSolid[object=cylindrecreux,h=2,r=1,fillcolor=cyan,ngrid=30 30 , linewidth= 0pt]
    \parametricplotThreeD[xPlotpoints=200,  linecolor=red, linewidth=1pt, plotstyle=curve, algebraic](0,TwoPi){1*cos(t) | 1*sin(t) | 0 }   
    \pstThreeDCoor[linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,IIIDxTicksPlane=xz, IIIDyTicksPlane=yz,spotX=180,xMin=-4,xMax=5,yMin=-2.25,yMax=4,zMin=-5,zMax=5,nameX=$x$, nameY=$y$, nameZ=$z$, labels=none] 
    \axesIIID(1,1,1.5)(3,3,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The axes seem to be "different." I am not really sure if this is due to the `Alpha` value given to try overlapping the respective axes.

My question is: Are the axes from the packages `pst-3dplot` and `pst-solides3d` just the same? Or are they different in some aspects? In case of the latter case, how do I modify the axes in such a way that the respective axes coincide or are the same?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it makes absolutely no sense to compare the two packages. `pst-solides3d` uses the central view with a viewpoint and a plane. For `pst-3dplot` with a parallel view there is in general no viewpoint and the plane is in infinity. Only for s3d objects `pst-3dplot` uses a viewpoint which defines only rotations.

Comment: I see. I would want to use `pst-3dplot` in creating space curves and then `pst-solides-3d` in creating 3D surfaces since creating surfaces using `pst-3dplot` is difficult.

Comment: It is no problem to mix the macros. It is only a problem if you want to compare views and coordinate values ...